# Keep formatting from rtf file in python

Tags: python, string, io, rtf

I have a bunch of rtf files with things like bolded and italicized text. They're organized in bullet points and I want to write a python script to reverse the bullet items. For eg.

```
•item 1
•item 2
•item 3
```

to

```
•item 3
•item 2
•item 1
```

I know how to reverse them, I'll use the newline char as a delimiter and separate to make the bullets into a list. Reversing a list is simple, I'm just not sure on how to preserve the bold formatting of the rtf file...

Comment: How do you read the rtf file?

Comment: look at [PyRTF](http://pyrtf.sourceforge.net/)